# Probability 3rd. Axiom: Finite and Infinite case

Tags: probability

Third Axiom in Probability states that:

> Probability of Union of **Infinite** number of disjoint events is
>   equal to sum of their probability.

I've seen that after stating this axioms, books go and Prove the exact same statement for **finite** number of disjoint events, that is:

> Probability of Union of **Finite** number of disjoint events is equal
>   to sum of their probability.

I am very confused. The infinite case is broader and should automatically cover the finite case. Why the finite case needs a proof when the broader statement is accepted as axiom?

Comment: The finite case is not an Axiom, so requires a proof from the axioms (even if the proof is simple).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, yes. My question is why. When we accepted its true for infinite case, finite case is already covered.

Comment: @doubleE and why is the finite case “already covered”? What’s the proof? This is not always immediate to everyone, and since it is not an axiom you need *some proof* no matter how trivial.

Comment: It should be emphasized that the third axiom requires countably infinite unions, not uncountably infinite unions. In other words, the given statement of the third axiom is not correct.

Comment: PS: Theorem: The sum of an infinite number of positive integers is infinity. But, this theorem does not imply the sum of a finite number of positive integers is infinity. So here is an example where the infinite case does not cover the finite case.